# Google Script - if criteria met run certain functions else do nothing

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below script with the purpose of retrieving the value in the google sheet which will either state TRUE or FALSE. If it states false I want this script to run the two functions below (updateWIPdata and updateDebtorsdata) but if the cell value is true I don't want those functions to run at all but the functions seem to run regardless of the value in the cell so any help would be much appreciated

```
function updateAll() {

var updateStatus = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Updated').getRange('C2').getValue();

Logger.log(updateStatus);
   
   if (updateStatus = 'false') {
 
   updateWIPdata();
   updateDebtorsdata();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the value is a `boolean`.

Also, please use `==` or `===`

```js
   if (updateStatus == false) {
```

Reference:

[Equality operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#equality_operators)

Answer (score 0):

## The fix is simple

### But you also want to improve a few things in your code

The main problem is in this line:

```js
if (updateStatus = 'false')
```

You are not comparing `updateStatus` to `false`, you are **assigning** `'false'`  to `updateStatus`. On top of that you are assigning a string, not a boolean. The line needs to be

```js
if (false === updateStatus)
```

Notice three things:

1. `false` is a boolean here, it doesn't have quotation marks around it
2. It's on the left side of the comparison; putting litteral values on the left side is a habbit that prevents this type of error
3. I'm using the `===` comparison operator instead of the `=` assignment operator

Another thing you need to do is forget about `var` and start using `const` and `let`. If your `updateStatus` was a `const`, you would have very quickly realized the error.